# How to list the API names of all managed package objects within salesforce organization

Tags: salesforce

I am trying list all the API Names available in a salesforce organization. I am able to retrieve all the object API names using below code:

```
for ( Schema.SObjectType o : Schema.getGlobalDescribe().values() )
{
    Schema.DescribeSObjectResult objResult = o.getDescribe();
    system.debug( 'Sobject: ' + objResult );
    system.debug( 'Sobject API Name: ' + objResult.getName() );
    system.debug( 'Sobject Label Name: ' + objResult.getLabel() );   
}
```

But the list does not contain the objects belongs to managed packages and unmanaged packages.

And also I am trying to access managed package objects records via workbench.developerforce.com , I am getting the error as

> message: Select COUNT(id) FROM CustomObject__c ^ ERROR at
>   Row:1:Column:23 sObject type 'CustomObject__c' is not supported. If
>   you are attempting to use a custom object, be sure to append the '__c'
>   after the entity name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call
>   for the appropriate names. errorCode: INVALID_TYPE

I did post question [developer.salesforce.com](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=9060G0000005UXVQA2) did not get the response yet.

**EDIT :**

Setup#QuickSearch#Objects this screen has the objects listed from managed packages but same objects not coming in `Schema.getGlobalDescribe().values()`.

Answer (score 0):

A managed object should contain two underscores before and after the object name:

`Namespace__CustomObject__c`

You should be able to identify it by the Namespace or by the fact that still it contains two consecutive underscores after removing `__c`

Comment: @SatishakumarAwati from what I have read you can get the Sobject Describe of a managed package object but may not be able to see it in Global Describe, do you have a user license to use the package?

Comment: I am not sure how accessibility works for managed objects, I can see the object listed in objects screen salesforce but does not come in Schema.getGlobalDescribe().values()

Answer (score 0):

In case someone is still looking for SOQL, This can be achieved using following SOQL as well

select sobjecttype from ObjectPermissions where parent.NamespacePrefix='PackageName'